# Find the coordinates of a specific pixel in rasterStack

Tags: r, coordinates, raster

I would like to find the pixels coordinates in a rasterStack that have the same pattern of a vector. Below is a simple example.

```
> s<-r<-raster(ncol=5,nrow=5)
> r[]<-round(runif(ncell(r)))
> s[]<-2
> rs<-stack(r,s)
> rs

class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 5, 5, 25, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : layer.1, layer.2 
min values  :       0,       2 
max values  :       1,       2
```

If I have a vector `vet<-c(0,2)`, which the pixels coordinates that have value 0 in the first layer and value 2 in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with `which` might work. I'm sticking with matrices; you can rasterize them later :-)

```
foo<-which(r==0,arr.ind=TRUE)
s<-matrix(ncol=5,nrow=5)
set.seed(10)
r[]<-round(runif(ncell(r)))
s[1:3,]<-2
foo<-which(r==0,arr.ind=TRUE)
bar<-which(s==2,arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Then look for identical rows in `foo` and `bar`, perhaps by concatenating rows, or calculating `foo-bar` and identifying zero rows.

EDIT:  a better way, giving you the coordinates right away.

```
which(s==2 & r==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
```